# Trouble understanding sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, adverbs

> 「質問に答えていない。
>   私は、人を殺すのが楽しいのかと訊いたのです」
>   サーヴァントを睨む。
>   歪な短刀を持った影は、
>   「**とりわけ何も。第一、殺しちゃ楽しめねえだろ、色々**」
>   ひひ、と。
>   愉しみを共有したがるよう、下卑た笑いを私に向けた。

What does that last sentence mean?
I think he is saying something like:

> Not particularly. For once, you can't have fun killing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

第一 (≂ そもそも) means "to begin with", or "in the first place".

殺しちゃ(=殺したら)楽しめねえだろ (≂ 殺してしまったら、楽しめないだろう) means "Once you have killed (people), you can't have fun (with them anymore)".

So he's saying he does not particularly enjoy killing people, and that he can't have fun anymore if he has killed them... (implying he enjoys doing *various* things to them before killing...)

Comment: So 色々 refers to 楽しめない?  色々 is what is giving me trouble.

Comment: 色々 adverbially modifies the verb 楽しめない. It's like "in various ways" "in many ways"... implying he actually has fun with these people in various ways... (probably like, toying with them, torturing, or hurting them...?)

Answer (score 0):

第一 means "besides all that", 'first of all"

殺しちゃ is the change of 殺しては and it means "if I kill (persons)" in this sentence.

楽しめねぇだろ is the change of 楽しめないだろ and it means "I can't have fun"

He says that "Not particularly. First of all, if I kill persons, I can't have fun in various ways." in the last sentence.

Comment: So 色々 refers to 楽しめない?  色々 is what is giving me trouble.

Comment: Yes, 色々 modifies the verb 楽しめない in this sentence.